# Using more components in JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a Jtable with three columns, 1st and 2nd column has textfield and 3rd column has textarea, If I am in 2nd column(Jtextfield), I want to find the component used in the 3rd column, how I will find that??

please give some suggestions.. Thanks in Advance Vishwa

Comment: Please tell me you haven't added components directly into the table model? Renderers and editors are determined by a combination of the class type return from TableModel#getColumnClass and the TableCellRenderer/Editor associated with the given class type or the TableColumn within the TableColumnModel

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes I have added the Editors and Renderers for each column

Comment: Why not simply use `JTable#getDefaultRenderer/Editor(Class)`?